# All Leather Sofa Creases

Tags: furniture

My new all-leather [sofa](http://www.ashleyfurniture.com/Showroom/Showroom.aspx?PageId=Showroom&CategoryID=1&ItemNo=4000138&SetDomTab=4&SeriesNo=40001&CollectionId=&style=1&IsClicked=1&CatPageNumber=1&bFromSearch=Y&Keyword=4000138) came in a few days ago. The inside fill is polyfoam. The cushions and armrest did not have any creases or wrinkles on it. However, after sitting on it a couple of times, creases are left on it. Shouldn't leather rebound after sitting? Can this be a quality issue from the leather?

I don't know if this is right place to ask this question but I am impressed by the advice given here so I hope some of you can share insight into this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about leather couches, and not about home improvement.

Comment: But it falls under cleaning and furniture.

Comment: Please see [this meta question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/753/33).  If you read the description of the [tag:furiture] tag, you'll see that your question; while about furniture, does not fit ("*furniture making, repair, and refinishing*"). Also, it doesn't appear that you're cleaning anything or asking how to clean anything.

Answer (score 2):

All leather upholstery will eventually develop a significant collection of wrinkles and creases with continued use. How fast these develop varies by material thickness, fill firmness, tightness of the cover, and the amount of weight and use the surface is subjected to. This should be considered part of the charm and character of a natural material.

This also softens the leather and makes it more compliant and comfortable. Maybe some people see an old leather chair as an ugly wrinkled old thing. I see a charming, well used and loved chair that is invitingly soft and comfortable that exudes tons of character.